# VESA mount any monitor?

Tags: display, vesa

I really am in need of a 2-3 monitor setup, I used to have dual monitors but I am down to 1 old crappy one now (had to sell my dual setup).  So now my search for something is on with:

- around 22-23 inches
- black glossy bevel
- VESA mount holes on the back (the 4
  holes in a square for mounting to
  custom monitor stands

So my question, can a monitor without the vesa style holes still be mounted like it has them?  IF not is there somewhere to find just monitors with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to make your own mounting adapter plate.  Find longer screws that fit the existing holes, and mark their pattern.  You might even be able to drill extra holes into an existing adapter.

Monitors usually use 75x75 or 100x100 hole patterns.  The screws are metric "M4", basically 4mm outer diameter, but I think the inner diameter 3.3mm for drilling.  VESA says 10mm long, plus a bit for the thickness of the metal.

I also saw a ["how to" video for making monitor hanger out of an old CD drive metal enclosure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWjJDOSRUnw).

But a safer idea might be to use or improvise some type of shelf.  For example, although the original non-VESA mount had 4 screw holes, I wonder if those screws bore all of the weight, or maybe they just kept it in place do that plastic parts did the real "lifting".

Answer (score 2):

If a monitor doesn't have a vesa mount, then it's likely that manually drilling 4 holes in its back will seriously damage it.

You can start your shopping with visiting a real physical computer store and physically check which models are vesa-mount capable.

Comment: He is suggesting drilling holes in the adapter/plate, not the display.

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting this remedy myself. My monitor is a new Asus VX220H and is really quite light so I'm certain the rear cover will support the weight without distortion over time. The original stand was just mounted to the plastic rear cover panel anyway

1. See Utube video on removing back cover or debezelling for your brand of monitor
2. remove stand and bracket from chassis.
3. obtain a Vesa adapter something like this one.  [http://www.amazon.com/Universal-Adapter-Medium-Mounts-Bracket/dp/B00U3DQO6I/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U3DQO6I).
4. drill 4 holes in the monitor rear panel to match either 75x75 or 100x100 hole patterns depending on your mount.
5. Beware of any areas where adapter might contact anything electrical inside monitor once it's reassembled. apply Universal adapter to inside of rear panel. Poster mount double sided tape should work nicely as it only needs to hold the mount in place while you are applying screws from the outside after cover is reinstalled.
6. reattach rear cover panel and screw mount in place from outside. The plastic rear cover panel will be sandwiched between the Vesa mount and the adapter so will be quite well supported especially if the larger 100x200 adapter will fit. there are 100x100 adapters available as well but select one that is thin as the monitor manufacturers will not give you much room inside the cover.